# How can I listen to music while running?

Tags: running, exercise-equipment

I want to listen to music while running, but I have a hard time finding a good way to do so.

My phone is quite big, and my watch is a standard running watch, not a smart watch. I live in a place with lots of rain, so the equipment must be water resistant.

I'm guessing wireless earbuds, but how can I bring the music with me?

Note: I'm not asking for product recommendations, but rather "solution recommendations". I.e. what sort of product(s) should I buy?

Comment: Belgium Here. Quite rainy aswell here. Most Earbuds are water resistant to some point. I use Bluetooth headphones with my Smartwatch. But it also works with a bluetooth MP3 player. Ran several times through the pouring rain without the earphones giving up. Don't be scared about that.

Comment: As far as running with your phone, I would recommend one of these waist belt things(https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00JF9DWWU/ref=cm_sw_r_tw_dp_U_x_.i5KDb38MM6M8). I've tried many different arm and leg bands, but this is by far the best way to carry a bulky device.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

- Get a small MP3 player.  Anything from an IPod nano to knockoffs that sell on Amazon.  [This one has a screen and is less than $20.](https://amzn.to/2nRI0hl)  While you will still have to carry it, you can probably fit it in one of the super secret pockets many running shorts have.  Some of my shorts have a pocket near the waist band on the back.  With that kind of setup you can use wireless or wired head phones.
- Get a watch that has music built in.  This is a more expensive option and it will require wireless head phones.
- Get a pouch to carry your phone and water.  [I use something like this because I run in the heat.](https://amzn.to/2nO0mjf)  This will cost you around $20, and I have used wired and wireless headphones with this setup.
- Get a running belt.  These tend to be less expensive than the previous option, but do not carry water.

Comment: Strongest recommendation for a 6th generation iPod Nano if you can find one -- best form factor, general design, and UX for running I've ever seen... no clue why Apple ever deviated from that design. Even includes a clip so you can clip to a sleeve, shirt hem, or pant/short waist hem if you want to have your hands free.

Comment: FYI - many (most?) running belts include water bottle pouches (see https://www.runnersworld.com/gear/g20865114/best-running-belts/ for examples).

Answer (score 2):

I've used and recommend headphones like the Sony Sports Walkman headphones that offer Bluetooth connectivity but also let you store music directly in the built-in memory (up to 4GB) so you can run without your phone and still have plenty of music. They sound great and are waterproof, you can even use them while swimming, so they lend themselves well to running. Battery life is about 8 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a phone (or music player) with a headphone socket use that, and put the phone in a water-resistant pouch.  This can be an armband, a backpack if you run with one, or for a really big phone a waist pouch.  My current phone doesn't fit any of my armbands so I sometimes carry it in my hand; this gets annoying after running a few km, especially as I always carry water. I use MP3s stored on my phone, because the signal isn't great where I live.

Wired headphones are cheap for the same sound quality as wireless, as well as being available in a range of styles and fits, so getting something you like is easy.  If one earbud falls out (IME more of an issue in the gym, but if you find yourself jumping over puddles this can happen running) it's still attached and you don't have to break stride to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

I regularly listen to music while running. I am using spotify on my mobile phone. Even if your phone is big, I would use it and try to get either something like an arm holder for the phone or have it in my hands. Carrying even more devices would not solve it for me.

In addition I am using wired headphones and locally synced music. Fiddeling with bluetooth or having no connection while running is not that pleasant. I have had that during a city run when my BT headset would not connect and I had to reboot the phone while running. In addition having thousands of runners around you limits your mobile connectivity. The best thing you can do in such a situation is go into flight mode (to force your streaming app to go offline) and continue running.

Answer (score 0):

I've bought Bluetooth headphones + Samsung Gear Fit 2 - it enables me to track my route via GPS through endomondo app and listen to music via Spotify (you need to have premium account and download playlist to the watch via Wi-Fi at home first)